# How to copy text of a web element depending upon a different element?

Tags: python

th class="field-number">[8901260165762549811](/admin/api/sim/128/change/) /th
td class="field-device">dawn-fog-3366 (3798) /td

I need to copy the field device for a specific field number and store it as a value. Is there any way I can do it without selenium?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Yes it is possible, you can for example use some XPATH lib to select the correct element.

Comment: no worries. I used beautiful soup 'next_sibling()' to get the field-device depending on the field-number.